# Finding the percentage in my while loop isn't working correctly. Is nested while loop ok?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner, decimalformat

I am trying to learn java while loops. I'm trying to make a program that will count passing test scores from a group of students and output the total number of scores inputted, the number of passing tests with a score above 69, and display the percentage of tests that passed.

The problem I am running into is I can't seem to get the percentage to output correctly. It keeps displaying 0.0. The following is the best code I came up with so far.

Is it good coding style to have a nested while loop? Is there a simpler way to shorten my program? Thanks

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class CountPassingScores {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Formats the percentage output to one decimal place.
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.0");

        // counts how many times a score is entered. Passing score is not
        // considered here.
        int count = 0;
        // The score the user enters.
        int score = 0;
        // percent of the class that passed the test. Passing score is 70 and
        // above.
        double percentOfClassPassed = 0.0;
        // total number of tests passed. Passing score is 70 and above.
        int numberOfTestsPassed = 0;

        System.out.println("This program counts the number of passing "
                + "test scores. (-1 to quit)\n");

        while (score != -1) {
            System.out.print("Enter the first test score:  ");
            score = scan.nextInt();

            while (count != -1 && score > 0) {
                System.out.print("Enter the next test score:  ");
                score = scan.nextInt();
                count++;

                if (count == -1)
                    break;
                else if (score > 69)
                    numberOfTestsPassed++;
                percentOfClassPassed = (numberOfTestsPassed / count);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("\nYou entered " + count + " scores.");
        System.out.println("The number of passing test scores is "
                + numberOfTestsPassed + ".");
        System.out.println(df.format(percentOfClassPassed)
                + "% of the class passed the test.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of **integer division**? If not try to google it and you will understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't consider 92 as a test passed score as you haven't incremented the value of numberOfTestsPassed in your first while loop. Hereby are a few changes I made in your code snippet:

```
    while (score != -1) {
        System.out.print("Enter the first test score:  ");
        score = scan.nextInt();
        if(score > 69)
        numberOfTestsPassed++;
        while (count != -1 && score > 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter the next test score:  ");
            score = scan.nextInt();
            count++;
            if (score == -1)
                break;
            else if (score > 69)
                numberOfTestsPassed++;
        }
         percentOfClassPassed = ((double)numberOfTestsPassed * 100 / count); 
    }
```

It gives the correct output for all inputs.

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it working correctly. I didn't think to add the extra if. How come numberOfTestsPassed isn't incremented twice, since there's two? and I wasn't sure how to fix the math part. thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are dividing an `int` from an `int`. Which will result in an `int` only.

To get proper result, cast any one to `double`.

```
percentOfClassPassed = ((double) numberOfTestsPassed / count);
```

Comment: ah I see, I haven't learned much on type casting yet. Thanks.

Comment: Whichever scores I entered I seem to get the same output. 0.5%.

Comment: Does anyone know why after I added. percentOfClassPassed = ((double) numberOfTestsPassed / count); it now outputs 0.5%?

Comment: could you help me again please

Comment: It's giving proper answers to me. One issue with your code is, you are computing percentage even if I give `-1` to exit. Instead of `if (count == -1)` use `if (score == -1)`. Also, since you are rounding off to single decimal place, you will only get approximate value.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the if. I didn't notice that. I found the problem why the percent wasn't displaying. I changed to this DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0%");

Comment: Now the below is the latest output. If you notice one of the passing scores isn't factored in and I'm not sure why. It should say 3 passed scores with 75.0%.  This program counts the number of passing test scores. (-1 to quit)

Enter the first test score:  92
Enter the next test score:  77
Enter the next test score:  55
Enter the next test score:  88
Enter the next test score:  -1

You entered 4 scores.
The number of passing test scores is 2.
66.7%% of the class passed the test.